# Apple Music API - search songs and create playlist (MacOS)

Tags: applescript, itunes, apple-music

I'm looking for API that would allow do these tasks

- Search song in Apple Music
- Create playlist
- Add songs to playlist

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

I'm afraid that what you are asking to do, is at the moment **not possible** *since starting from iTunes 12.2 we can only search the local library and not the entire Apple Music from the API*.

In the case you have the song that you want to play inside your library(local or cloud), you can search and play a song like this :

```
tell application "iTunes"
    set results to (every track whose name contains "Cumuli" and artist is "883")
    repeat with tune in results
        play tune
    end repeat
end tell
```

And then you can put the retrieved tune inside the playlist you want, or create a new one. Take a look at [this post for an example](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/2767095?start=0&tstart=0).